# How to get brightness keys working inside openbox session?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, openbox, brightness

I'm using **Openbox** window manager **without DE**.

I'd like to get **`fn + [brightness up/down icon]`** working like it is in GNOME/KDE, but I’m looking for a lightweight solution without gnome-power-manager and similar.

I know about the `xbacklight` console program, but it takes a little time to adjust brightness.

Comment: On the few laptops I have owned, the brightness keys have never been handled by the window manager or desktop environment.  Instead, I think the acpi package or the kernel supported those keys directly.  Do you have all the relevant acpi packages installed and does your kernel support your hardware?

Comment: There is a good summary of this issue on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight)

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
xrandr –-output LVDS1 –-set BACKLIGHT 5
```

Or values other than "5".

See http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/how-to-change-screen-brightness-of.html

Comment: worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 2):

Control brightness without `sudo`:

Install `brightnessctl` and `brightness-udev`.

Then use:

```bsh
brightnessctl set 10+   # to increase brightness by 10
brightnessctl set 10-   # to decrease brightness by 10

brightnessctl set 10%+  # to increase brightness by 10%
brightnessctl set 10%-  # to decrease brightness by 10%

brightnessctl set 50%   # to set brightness to 50%
```

Use `man brightnessctl` for a full list of commands available.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working guide on [this webpage](http://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Openbox%3a_Control_Screen_Brightness_Using_the_Keyboard). You have to have installed the `xbacklight` program, on Fedora 18:

```
sudo yum install xbacklight
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two similar things:

a) brightness of the monitor (gamma value)

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --brightness 0.8
```

b) blacklight of the lamp in the monitor

```
bl_device=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness 
 #or settings in here: /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
echo $(($(cat $bl_device)+1)) | sudo tee $bl_device # brightness up
```

So we should take care of two variables. :-)